# Columns and Arguments AWK Parameters in Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, unix, awk, arguments, sh

I want to get positional parameters as arguments for my .sh file and I also want to get fields from a text file for awk. I've figured out that I need to use $1-$9 for both and its okay to use the same number $() in awk as a positioning parameter, it still works.

e.g. I call my shell script like this

```
./myProgram myFile.txt 1 2 3 4
```

Then within my shell script I want to use `awk` to refer to fields in a text file like this, specifically 1,2:3,4 the last four fields.

```
0000000022:trevor:736:1,2:3,4
0000000223:john:73:5,6:7,8
0000002224:eliza:54:9,8:7,6
0000022225:paul:22:5,4:3,2
0000222226:chris:0:1,2:3,4
```

So I can go through the fields, however when I do because there are two types of field separators it doesn't seem to work.

My shell script so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"

awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "u1 =", $u1 }' $1
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "v1 =", $v1 }' $1
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "u2 =", $u2 }' $1
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "v2 =", $v2 }' $1

echo "Argument #1 =" $2
echo "Argument #2 =" $3
echo "Argument #3 =" $4
echo "Argument #4 =" $5
```

This is the output I get from terminal:

```
u1 = 1
u1 = 5
u1 = 9
u1 = 5
u1 = 1
v1 = awk: illegal field $(), name "v1"
 input record number 1, file database.txt
 source line number 1
u2 = awk: illegal field $(), name "u2"
 input record number 1, file database.txt
 source line number 1
v2 = awk: illegal field $(), name "v2"
 input record number 1, file database.txt
 source line number 1
Argument #1 = 1
Argument #2 = 2
Argument #3 = 3
Argument #4 = 4
```

I'm so close yet so far, I'm not sure why I'm not able to go further across the fields using my awk script?

Comment: By coordinates, I assume you mean fields. There are several problems with your awk commands, but you should first explain better what you're trying to do (using words), and show _expected_ sample output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWK Multiple Field Separators and Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343106/awk-multiple-field-separators-and-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: It seems that the OP's problem stemmed from confusion over the distinction between *shell parameters* (`$1`, `$2`, ...) with *input-field* variables in *Awk* - which can *look* the same, but are entirely unrelated.
Specifically, the incorrect assumption was made that if `n` parameters were passed to the *shell* script, *Awk*'s input-field numbering would start with `n+1`.

---

The following snippet - originally written before the OP added more code to the question - demonstrates the **interplay of shell parameters and *Awk* variables**, followed by a detailed explanation.

Specifically, it defines *Awk* variables `fi1` and `fi2` based on the values of *shell* parameters `$2` and `$3` respectively, which contain 1-based *field indices* relative to the lines in file `$file`.

Then, inside the Awk program, the field indices stored in `fi1` and `fi2` are used first *as is* (no `$` prefix) to print their own value, and then to reference the corresponding input-line *fields* by prepending `$` (variable references in *Awk* are NOT `$`-prefixed - the `$` is only used to refer to *fields*).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"

awk -F'[:,]' -v fi1=$2 -v fi2=$3 \
  '{ print "Field #" fi1 " + field #" fi2 " =", $fi1 + $fi2 }' "$file"
```

- The shell and `awk` are separate worlds, and do not see each other's variables.

  - You can see *environment* variables in `awk`, by accessing the `ENVIRON` associative array, but you cannot see *shell* variables.
  - You *can* implicitly "bake" shell-variable values into an `awk` program by passing a *double-quoted* string with shell-variable references - which are expanded *before* `awk` sees the program - but that gets confusing quickly and should be avoided.
  - Conversely, the only way to pass values *back* from `awk` to the shell is to have awk print to stdout and use a shell command substitution to capture the result in a shell variable.
- You can pass the values of shell parameters and variables *to awk variables* using instances of the `-v` option, as demonstrated above.

  - Here we know that the values are numbers, so we don't strictly need to double-quote the var. references, but it in general it's advisable.
- **Inside `awk`, its variables are referenced *without* the `$` prefix, and `$` is *only* used to refer to *input fields***:

  - `$fi1`, perhaps somewhat confusingly, therefore means: get the input *field* (prefix `$`) whose index is stored in `awk` *variable* `fi1` (by contrast, using `fi1` as is, without a prefix, would return the *index*).
- **Field indices in `awk` are always *1*-based**, relative to each line of input.

  - For instance, inside `awk`, `$1` refers to the *first field on the current input line*, and even though it *looks* the same as the 1st script / function parameter in the *shell*, they have absolutely nothing to do with each other.
  - Additionally, `$0` contains the *entire* current input line, and `NF` contains the *number* (count) of input fields.

Comment: I seem to be getting there not sure what is wrong with my awk line though now @mklement0

Comment: @JoshuaVernon: The problem now is that you're seemingly creating Awk variables _without a value_, which cause field references based on that value - `$<varname>` - to FAIL (if `varname` evaluates to the empty string, `$` by itself is obviously not a valid field index). Your particular error message suggests that shell parameters `$6`, `$7`, and `$8` are NOT SET. Note how in your debugging code you're only printing through `$5`, whereas your Awk commands define variables based on up to `$8`.

Comment: You're right. I've learnt to use $(NF-1) now which seems to work well within an awk