# AWK Multiple Field Separators and Variables

Tags: bash, shell, awk, field, sh

I am trying to perform calculations in awk using fields whose numbers are passed in from the shell, as well as the last four fields

e.g. I call my shell script like this

```
./myProgram myFile.txt 1 2 3 4
```

Then within my shell script I want to use `awk` to refer to fields in a text file like this, specifically the last four fields. $(NF-3) - $(NF)

```
0000000022:trevor:736:1,2:3,4
0000000223:john:73:5,6:7,8
0000002224:eliza:54:9,8:7,6
0000022225:paul:22:5,4:3,2
0000222226:chris:0:1,2:3,4
```

So I can go through the fields, however when I do because there are two types of field separators it doesn't seem to work.

My shell script so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"

awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "u1 =", $u1 }' $1
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "v1 =", $v1 }' $1
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "u2 =", $u2 }' $1
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "v2 =", $v2 }' $1

echo "Argument #1 =" $2
echo "Argument #2 =" $3
echo "Argument #3 =" $4
echo "Argument #4 =" $5
```

This is the output I get from terminal:

```
u1 = 1
u1 = 5
u1 = 9
u1 = 5
u1 = 1
v1 = awk: illegal field $(), name "v1"
 input record number 1, file database.txt
 source line number 1
u2 = awk: illegal field $(), name "u2"
 input record number 1, file database.txt
 source line number 1
v2 = awk: illegal field $(), name "v2"
 input record number 1, file database.txt
 source line number 1
Argument #1 = 1
Argument #2 = 2
Argument #3 = 3
Argument #4 = 4
```

Comment: Using $ to access variables in awk,dont.Unless of course you meant to in which case maybe you should have values for the variables you set at the start. You have `u1=$5` yet you've only passed 4 args to the script.Also what are those backslashes for ?Also not 100% but i'm pretty sure leaving a space after the shebang will cause it not to work.

Comment: I took out the backslashes, thanks. However when I take out the $ from u1 then it comes up with u1=4 for each line

Comment: Why are you passing 1 2 3 4 if you want to access the last four fields ?

Comment: Thats a second part of the task but was something I got really confused about because I had to both pass positioning parameters and access fields and I thought it would stuff up if I was referring to both of them using the $1-$9 notation so I left it there to make sure people thought it was correct to do so. I'm going to actually do calculations using all of those elements @JID

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you want to do, showing a full example. At the moment, we are guessing at your requirements.

Comment: What will you do with thoose u1 after ? (it's awk which print them, getting them back in a variety in your bash won't work as you expect it Is think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$N` in awk, it will retrieve field `N`. You can use this in combination with passing arguments to awk as you have done to access a field number defined in a shell variable. The main issue would appear to be that you are passing variables that haven't been set in your script.

In your example invocation of the script, you're not passing enough arguments for positional parameters `$6` and above to be defined. This is what is causing your error messages that look like `illegal field $()`, because `v1` is an empty string, so you're attempting to get a field with no number.

`NF` is a special variable in awk that contains the number of fields, so to access the last four fields, you can use `$(NF-3)`, `$(NF-2)`, `$(NF-1)`, and `$NF`.

There was a `\` before the awk command which wasn't doing anything useful, so I removed that as well.

There are a couple of other issues with your code that are worth mentioning too. Quote your shell variables! This prevents issues with word splitting on more complex variables. If your arguments are numbers with no spaces, this won't make any difference but it does no harm either and is a good practice to get into. You've defined `file`, so I've used that instead of `$1`.

Combining those changes, we end up with something like this:

```
awk -F'[:,]' -v u1="$2" -v v1="$3" -v u2="$4" -v v2="$5" '{ print "u1 =", u1 }' "$file"
```

Comment: I get this output when I change that:     u1 = 4
u1 = 4
u1 = 4
u1 = 4
u1 = 4
v1 = 
v1 = 
v1 = 
v1 = 
v1 = 
u2 = 
u2 = 
u2 = 
u2 = 
u2 = 
v2 = 
v2 = 
v2 = 
v2 = 
v2 = 
Argument #1 = 1
Argument #2 = 2
Argument #3 = 3
Argument #4 = 4

Comment: @JoshuaVernon I've added to my explanation, hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: @TomFenech I actually do want to get the fields. So how would I use $N to get the fields. I then will use the last four fields of each line to make calculations against the four positional parameters

Comment: @JoshuaVernon add the `$` back in and use `$(NF-3)` up to `$NF` to access the four last fields?

Comment: @JoshuaVernon thanks for accepting my answer - I'm glad you found my explanation useful. However, it would still be good to edit your question so that your requirements were clearer, then I can edit my answer so that they match up correctly. It seems like my comment was probably the answer in the end!

Comment: @TomFenech Yes the comment was the answer. I have edited the end of my question to explain what the answer was and I changed the start of the question to better word what I was asking. Please advise me if it needs further work. I'm very knew to stack exchange but am starting to understand and admire the culture so I'd love to whenever I ask a question it to be easy to follow

Comment: @JoshuaVernon the best format is usually something like **1** a clear problem statement: "I am trying to perform calculations in awk using fields whose numbers are passed in from the shell, as well as the last four fields" **2** a sample of your data (done) **3** your attempt (done) **4** the problem you're experiencing (done). You should remove the "answer" part of your question to make it more brief and improve the introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Just about one line:

`awk -F'[:,]' -v u1=$5 -v v1=$6 -v u2=$7 -v v2=$8 \ '{ print "u1 =", $u1 }' $1`

Here $5,$6,$7 and $8 are the bash positional parameters not awk field position.
Here you have 5 parameters to your script according to your command line:

`./myProgram myFile.txt 1 2 3 4`

```
$1 = myFile.txt
$2 = 1
$3 = 2
$4 = 3
$5 = 4
$6 = 
$7 =
$8 =
```

That's why awk alert your only on the call to `$v1` as it's equivalent to `$` and is not a field value.

If I understood properly your problem you wish to get the line where the 4 last paramters match thoose values:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{ print "u1=",$(NF-3),"v1=",$(NF-2),"u2=",$(NF-1),"v2=",$NF }' "$1"
```

NF being the number of field, minus 3 give the 4 field before the end.

Comment: I wish to get the last four fields of each line in the txt file and save them to variables so I can then use both the positional parameters and the last four fields of each line and make calculations. I just haven't even been able to get the last four parameters to print them out to see if I am getting them correctly

Comment: @JoshuaVernon I edited to print the 4 last fields, if you want to do something with them before output you'll have to work within awk or call another script with them as parameters, without the real case it's hard to guess what you want to do at all.

Comment: @JoshuaVernon you realise that awk goes through the whole file so your variable would either contain every single line or just the last line ?